# How I create objects for 2 Collection of Mongodb?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently doing a project about note taking application. before that i only have knowladge about handling one collection in mongodb. but in this application, i try to create user can add note add add that note to prefered category. in this process user can select prefered categories.(Gernaral, Todo) .. but also user can create own new category. when user create new category it will save it in db and it show with that already created category(stored in db).

I created routes and dev db. All work fine. note was created.

//server.js

```
//other mongo db connections
app.use('/note', NoteRoutes)
app.use('/category', CategoryRoutes)
```

//NoteRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { getAllNoteData, getOneNoteData, addNewNote, updateNote, deleteNote } = require('../controller/noteController.js');




//routes for get all Note Data
router.get('/', getAllNoteData)

//routes for get specific Data
router.get('/:id', getOneNoteData)

//routes for add new note
router.post('/', addNewNote)

//update the exsist note
router.put('/:id', updateNote)

//delete the exsist note
router.delete('/:id', deleteNote)



//export rounter
module.exports = router;
```

//categoryRoute.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { getCategory, createCategory } = require('../controller/categoryController.js');

//create new category
router.post('/category', createCategory)

//get all categories
router.get('/category', getCategory)

//export rounter
module.exports = router;
```

//noteController.js

```
//imported required modules
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Note = require("../models/notemodels")
const Category = require("../models/category")

//get all notes from db
const getAllNoteData = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        //all data assign to notes variable and sort by created date 
        const notes = await Note.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 })
            //return success response and pass data and number of notes using JSON format
        return res.status(200).json({
            count: notes.length,
            data: notes
        })
    } catch (error) {
        //error handling
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}


//get specific note based on id
const getOneNoteData = async(req, res) => {

    const { id } = req.params;
    try {
        //find the note by id and assign it into notes variable if requested data exsist
        const notes = await Note.findById({ _id: id })

        //if no data found then send not found status else pass success status
        if (!notes) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "No user found" });
        } else {
            return res.status(200).json(notes);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        //error handling
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}


//add new note
const addNewNote = async(req, res) => {
    try {

        const { title, content, category } = req.body;

        if (!title || !content) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: "Please fill out all input fields" })
        }

        let categoryObj = await Category.findOne({ name: category });
        if (!categoryObj) {
            categoryObj = new Category({ name: category });
            await categoryObj.save();
        }

        const newNote = {
            title: req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content,
            category: categoryObj._id
        }

        const note = await Note.create(newNote)
        return res.status(200).send({ data: note, message: "New Note added successfully" })


    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}


//update exsist note
const updateNote = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        if (!req.body.title || !req.body.content) {
            return res.status(400).send("Complete all the empty spaces")
        }

        const { id } = req.params;

        const note = await Note.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body);

        if (!note) {
            return res.send("No such note found!").status(400)
        } else {
            return res.send("Update Completed Successfully!").status(400)
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

const deleteNote = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const delNote = await Note.findByIdAndDelete(id);

        if (!delNote) {
            return res.status(400).send("No Note Found with this ID");
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send("Note Deleted Successfully")
        }


    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
}

//export the functions
module.exports = { getAllNoteData, getOneNoteData, addNewNote, updateNote, deleteNote }
```

//category controller.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Category = require("../models/category")


const getCategory = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const categories = await Category.find({}).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
        return res.status(200).json(categories);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching categories:', error);
        console.error('Error details:', error.message); // Log error message
        return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
};

//create new category
const createCategory = async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name } = req.body;
        let category = await Category.findOne({ name });

        if (!category) {
            category = new Category({ name });
            await category.save();
        } else {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Category already exists' });
        }
        res.status(201).json(category);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
    }
}

module.exports = { getCategory, createCategory };
```

In here when i created note object it created fine and display like this

```
 {
            "_id": "65fc8105c24e467d7397f3b4",
            "title": "Make coffie",
            "content": "use today to it",
            "color": "white",
            "category": "65fc7dcc97c1e426998de3f7",   //category object
            "createdAt": "2024-03-21T18:48:37.866Z",
            "updatedAt": "2024-03-21T18:48:37.866Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
```

it also created object id. that mean somewhere it created.

but when i try to go to see category, it show this

```
http://localhost:3000/category


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot GET /category</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

but when i add this it show this

```
http://localhost:3000/note/category


{
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ _id: 'category' }\" (type Object) at path \"_id\" for model \"Note\""
}
```

can someone help me to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mount your second router here:

```js
app.use('/category', CategoryRoutes)
```

All of the routes inside `CategoryRoutes` **implicitly** begin with `/category`.

So these routes are prefixed with `/category`:

```
router.post('/category', createCategory);
// Translates to http://localhost:3000/category/category

router.get('/category', getCategory)
// Translates to http://localhost:3000/category/category
```

You need to change them to:

```js
//create new category
router.post('/', createCategory)
// Translates to http://localhost:3000/category

//get all categories
router.get('/', getCategory)
// Translates to http://localhost:3000/category
```

This explains why you were getting the `Cannot GET /category` because that route doesn't exist in your router.

In your second example when you issued a `GET` request to:

```html
http://localhost:3000/note/category
```

Express routed the request to here:

```js
app.use('/note', NoteRoutes)
```

then here:

```js
//routes for get specific Data
router.get('/:id', getOneNoteData)
```

It assumed the word `category` was the `:id` parameter and tried to cast the word `category` to an `ObjectId` in the `getOneNoteData` function and obviously couldn't because `category` is not a castable value.